# Log in and get access token using Auth0 React SDK and Authorization Code Flow with PKCE leads to infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, authentication, authorization, auth0, pkce

I have implemented the Auth0 React SDK along with the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE to obtain an access token in my React Single Page Application (SPA) for making API calls to my protected backend routes.

I chose the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE because SPAs are considered public apps, not confidential ones. Therefore, we cannot obtain an access token using the standard Authorization Code Flow.

When I use the loginWithRedirect() function, everything works smoothly after users are authenticated. However, after implementing the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, which involves generating a link for user authentication and authorization with a code verifier and code challenge, users are redirected repeatedly to the redirect URL. Furthermore, the redirected links contain different values for the code query parameter each time.

Here is the link of the [Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce#javascript-sample)

Below is my code and the screenshot that demonstrates the problem.

**Auth0Provider setup**

```
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

import React from "react";

export const Auth0ProviderComponent = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const domain = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL;
  const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const redirectUri = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_FRONTEND_URL;

  if (!(domain && clientId && redirectUri)) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

**main.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { Auth0ProviderComponent } from "./components/Auth0ProviderComponent.tsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0ProviderComponent>
      <App />
    </Auth0ProviderComponent>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading, user } = useAuth0();

  function base64URLEncode(input: any) {
    const words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(input);
    const base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words);

    return base64.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=+$/, "");
  }

  function sha256(input: any) {
    const words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(input);
    const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(words);

    return hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated && !user) {
      //Create verifier
      const randomBytes = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32); // 32 bytes
      const verifier = base64URLEncode(
        randomBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
      );

      // Use the previously generated verifier to create the challenge code
      const challenge = base64URLEncode(sha256(verifier));

      //Generate link to authenticate and authorize users
      const config = {
        response_type: "code",
        client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        code_challenge: challenge,
        code_challenge_method: "S256",
        redirect_uri: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_FRONTEND_URL,
        audience: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_AUDIENCE,
        scope: "read:user-resources",
      };
      const generatedLink = `https://${
        import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL
      }/authorize?${new URLSearchParams(config).toString()}`;

      //Use the link
      window.location.href = generatedLink;
    }

    if (!isLoading && isAuthenticated && user) {
      alert("successfully log in");
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, isLoading, user]);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home page</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Infinite loop in which users are redirected to this redirect uri with different values of the code query.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**When I log isAuthenticated and user states, they are always false and undefined respectively.**

[image]

I am very grateful for your helps. It has been quite a long time that I have been stuck with this bug. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it keeps authenticating in an infinite loop because u add isloading and isAuthenticated to the useEffect dependency array. It just means everytime you will try logging in , and it will start loading then the useEffect will work again and will generate another link

Comment: I have removed these dependencies from the useEffect, and there is no longer an infinite loop. However, users are still not being authenticated correctly.

I have added a useEffect to log the isAuthenticated and user states whenever these values change, but they are always false and undefined. This indicates that the link is being generated multiple times because the user has never been authenticated correctly, not because useEffect has been implemented repeatedly.

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isAuthenticated,user);
  }, [isAuthenticated, user, isLoading]);

Comment: In this situation check the following:

https://community.auth0.com/t/isauthenticated-always-returns-false-react/60039

Also in the Auth0provider component you have to add the redirectUri prop, for example:

<Auth0Provider
        domain="......"
        clientId="......."
        redirectUri={window.location.origin}
        audience={"......"}
        scope={"....."}
    >